# Rules for cofiguring gateway IP

Tags: networking, gateway

I just wanted to know are there any rules for assigning an IP address to a default gateway.
Are there some rules that need to be followed, depending on the subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

The default gateway address is assigned by **DHCP**. If your computer is using this method to get an **IP** and it isn't getting a gateway, then the router is not doing it's job and needs to be checked. To manually set a default gateway, you will also have to assign a static **IP** address and **DNS** server address to the computer.
        To do this on either XP or Vista, you will need to go to the Control Panel (getting here is different for each) and select the Network Connections applet. Choose your internet interface (assuming you may have more than one listes) and right-click and select properties. This will open the connection properties sheet. In the list of items installed you will select Internet Protocol (IPv4 on Vista) and again click the properties. This will open the place you will need to enter the computer's static IP and Gateway and DNS. Unless you are an advanced computer user and can troubleshoot computer networks well, this action is not advised. Setting a static IP on a network with an unmanaged DHCP server can create a duplicate IP address error and prevent both computers from accessing the internet.

[Default gateway defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway).

Comment: Hey thanks jhon, for an instant reply,, however, i wanted to ask that, i am writing a tool to change the IP address of the gateway itself, but i am confused, can any IP address in the network be assigned to the gateway.
I am talking about configuring the router not the computer. :)

Comment: In Windows you can write the batch file & in Linux/Unix write Make file for this purpose..!!!